# SOQL Showing null values as 0

Tags: soql, query

If a record is not found, can I have it show a 0, instead of not appearing in my results?

For example: If I'm getting the total # of records for 5 different picklist values, and 1 picklist have has 0 records, I want it to show 0 instead of not showing that 5th picklist value at all.

Comment: You essentially have to query for the data beforehand to do that.

Answer (score 3):

No, SOQL won't show "empty" buckets in the result set, so it will be up to your code to properly render those zero-value entries.